# Passing Parameter Value as Value of Variable

Tags: java, variables, parameters

Basically I'm making a game where I need to add health to characters.  When the player hits the spider's hit box, I want the health to change and my frame to repaint. I feel like I'm doing it right.  Here is my code:

`Frame.java`:

```
public static int redHealth;
public static int blueHealth;

public static void getBlueHealth(int health) {
    health = redHealth;
}

public static void getRedHealth(int health) {
    health = blueHealth;
}

// Create health labels
public static JLabel redHealthLabel = new JLabel("Health: " + redHealth);
public static JLabel blueHealthLabel = new JLabel("Health: " + blueHealth);
```

`Key.java`:

```
if (Frame.spiderObj.intersects(Frame.blueCharacterObj)) {
    System.out.println("hit spider");
    Frame.getBlueHealth(97);
    Frame.frame.repaint();
    System.out.println(Frame.redHealth + "" + Frame.blueHealth);
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing `97` as a parameter into the `getRedHealth()` and `getBlueHealth()` methods, which is then set to equal `redHealth` and `blueHealth`.  However when I run my game and hit the spider, it prints out `hit spider` but does not update the health.

Any help???

Comment: Your assignments are backwards; you want `redHealth = health` and `blueHealth = health`.

Comment: I suggest you review your [Java basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Comment: First, I suggest you change your `getXXX()` methods to `setXXX()` since you are changing the values, not reading them. Second, I suggest that you add some SOP statements or use a debugger to figure out what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your big problem is that you are trying to "pass by reference" to populate `health` rather than actually returning it.

Should be:

```
public static int getBlueHealth() {
    return blueHealth;
}
```

Also: you probably don't need a getter since bluehealth is already `public static`.

Even if you could pass by reference, calling it with a constant would fail. Not clear from your calling code whether you want getters or setters.

Comment: Thanks John and isbadawi :) Fixed my problem.  Cheers!